# Error when requesting an API Cloudflare. Why?

Tags: php, api, cloudflare

when I am run the following code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST ["name"]; // its ZoneID
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$name/settings/ipv6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"value\":\"off\"}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Auth-Email: MAIL';
$headers[] = 'X-Auth-Key: TOKEN';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

var_dump($result);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I get in response:

"{“success”:false,“errors”:[{“code”:7000,“message”:“No route for that URI”}],“messages”:[],“result”:null}"

$name I need to get from the form

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: What have you tried to debug your problem?

Comment: I need to run this script, but it is not running

Comment: What do you mean by "not running"? Doesn't it return whatever the API returns, which is that given error message?

Comment: @NicoHaase this script should make changes via the api but nothing happens,  it must be so: {
 "success": right,
 "errors": [],
 "information": [],
 "result": {
 "id": "Polish",
 "value": "off.",
 "editable": true,
 "modified_on": "2014-01-01T05: 20: 00.12345 Z"
 }
}

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? As the response tells you, Cloudflare does not offer any service under the posted URL - have you checked whether its correct?